# Three.js and frame animation skipping

Tags: animation, three.js, frame

I'm currently using three.js for my projects with animation. I'm using morphtargets and wanted to ask why my frames are often skipped? My animation has 7 morphtargets, and it goes all around them. It starts from 0 to 6 (output:console.log('frame: ' + lastKeyframe) ) , but sometimes my frame jumps from 0 to 3 or from 1 to 4.. What happens here really? Btw, the animation code is working well

```
[if ( Mesh && playBack ) // exists / is loaded 
{   
    time = new Date().getTime() % duration; //arba Date.now()
    keyframe = Math.floor( time / interpolation ) + animOffset;
    if ( keyframe != currentKeyframe ) 
    {
        Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ lastKeyframe ] = 0;
        Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ currentKeyframe ] = 1;
        Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ keyframe ] = 0;
        //console.log(Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ]);
        lastKeyframe = currentKeyframe;
        currentKeyframe = keyframe;

    }
    //The two lines after the if statement interpolate between frames. 
    //The value at currentKeyFrame starts decreasing from 1, and the value at keyFrame starts increasing.
    Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ keyframe ] = ( time % interpolation ) / interpolation;
    Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ lastKeyframe ] = 1 - Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ keyframe ];
    //console.log('current: ' + Mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ keyframe ]);
    console.log('frame: ' + lastKeyframe);

}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because you are selecting the new frame based on reading a wall clock.. so it seems likely that if your frame rate drops then you'll lose a frame